# Specified cast is not valid in lambda expression of DataRow List while fetching a column value

Tags: c#, lambda, casting, datatable

I've a DataTable `orders` and I'm using lambda expression to filter out the records without any loops. The first line in the if condition works fine and returns me a valid record.

```
if (orders.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //This line returns a record
    var defaultOrder = orders.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(p => p.Field<bool>("IsDefault")).ToList();
    //The line below gives me an exception  Specified cast is not valid.
    var defaultOrderID = orders.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(p => p.Field<bool>("IsDefault")).Select(p => p.Field<long>("OrderID")).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Now, I want to fetch value of a specific column from this record but I'm getting following exception

[image]

PS: I can see in DB and `defaultOrder` variable in debug mode that value of `OrderID` is **4**.
Datatype of `IsDefault` is **bit** and `OrderID` is **int** in Database. Both are *not null*.

Comment: what is the field type of IsDefault and OrderId in database table?

Comment: Details updated in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the data type of the field "OrderID" in DataRow,
Rows will have no. of records under it, Expand any 1 record, Column properties,  Select the field "OrderID" and check the data type of it.

If it is giving error for long and it has value 4 in DB than it should have a data type of Int32, use that one.

```
var defaultOrderID = orders.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(p => p.Field<bool>("IsDefault")).Select(p => p.Field<Int32>("OrderID")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

if `OrderID` is Type of `int`

replace

```
p.Field<long>("OrderID")
```

with

```
 p.Field<int>("OrderID")
```